# wordpressのAMP解除

Tags: wordpress

wordpressでAMPを導入したのですが、
解除しようと思っています。

ネットで調べたのですが、AMP解除時に起こるページの切替期間が一週間ほどかかるという情報がありました。
出来る限り切替期間を短くしたいと思っています。

切替期間を短縮する方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/133091

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qiita.com/nobu0605/items/472bbdd4833158a26197

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/10551

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11192324856